# Can I make a Poller start his cycle with WAIT after start() command?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, poller

In my Integration Flow I change from standard flow to an error flow in some error condition, stopping the `standardStateEntryPoint` and starting the `errorStateEntryPoint` via sending the start/stop command messages to the `Control Channel`.

The `errorStateEntryPoint` is this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorStateEntryPoint() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            () -> new GenericMessage<String>(""),
                    e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(ERROR_STATE_POLLING))
                    .id("errorStateSourcePollingChannelAdapter")
                    .autoStartup(false))
            .channel("httpOutRequest")
            .get();
}
```

It has a `Poller` with a fixed delay of 5_000 ms. The recognized lifecycle when started is

```
send -> wait -> send -> wait etc.
```

Is it possible to have the inverse lifecycle, starting with the delay?

```
wait -> send -> wait -> send etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've found out:

You might set the initialDelay of the poller. If your poller has a period of 5.000 milliseconds without an initial delay, it is working this way:

```
send -> wait -> send -> wait  etc.
```

If you set the same 5.000 milliseconds as initial delay, it is working exactly as required:

```
wait -> send -> wait -> send etc.
```

The initial delay is the second argument setting `p.fixedDelay(...)`. Then the `errorStateEntryPoint` polling channel adapter should be this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorStateEntryPoint() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            () -> new GenericMessage<String>(""),
                    e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(ERROR_STATE_POLLING, ERROR_STATE_POLLING))
                    .id("errorStateSourcePollingChannelAdapter")
                    .autoStartup(false))
            .channel("httpOutRequest")
            .get();
}
```

That's it.